# evaluating perl code securely in a virtual machine online

Tags: linux, perl, amazon-ec2, virtualization

**update 2**: I got this working and it's live :)

**update:** Please check the comments, @ikegami answer is working but with a slight problem. I may be doing something pretty simple wrong.

---

I recently decided I had to learn Linux/Perl really well, and then I started building this [www.tryperl.com](http://www.tryperl.com) as a learning project. It's a **Cloud IDE** of sorts.

*(It's only been a few months since I first laid hands on perl, linux, bash, osx, so please go easy on me)*

Currently I eval code with [Safe.pm](https://metacpan.org/source/RGARCIA/Safe-2.33/Safe.pm), but my game plan is :

A separate Amazon EC2 VM that will eval **unsafe** perl code and return the result. The VM will be blocked from the internet and load balanced. I can then reset this machine from a snapshot every now and then.

This is *mostly* the code I will use to eval perl code on the server, I use [Time::Out](https://metacpan.org/module/PATL/Time-Out-0.11/Out.pod) for timeout management:

```
my $code = ..
my $arg = ..

#create a file with random name
my $filename = rand().".pl";
open(FILE,">$filename")
print FILE $code;
close(FILE);

#use Time::Out to timeout after 10 secs

my $ret = timeout 10 => sub {
  #run the file just created with $arg as an argument. << This is IMP 
  my $r = `perl $filename $arg`;
  return $r;
};
if ($@){
    return $@;
}   
return $ret;
```

My **Issues**

1. <strike>Can I somehow **avoid physical file creation** and pipe the $code **with the $arg**? 
   Like `open(FILE,"perl <some_magic> | ")`. Might sound stupid but I had to ask :(</strike>.
   This has been solved by @ikegami in the comments.
2. I can't seem to use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Capture%3a%3aTiny). I tried doing this inside the **timeout block**:
   `my ($stdout, $stderr, $count) = capture { system('echo Hello') };`
   But I kept getting empty strings! :( Is it because it's inside the timeout? (I don't care too much about this though)
3. Are there any other security flaws I'm not seeing? Should I be doing a **fork limit**? How should I begin doing that? (Links and some pointers would be nice)
4. The author of http://www.perltuts.com says in [this article](http://showmetheco.de/articles/2012/7/perltuts-interactive-perl-tutorials.html) he uses qemu and a debian image to run his code. Apart from fork limiting, **Is his approach semantically similar to mine ?** (Forgive my ignorance here again, Remember I touched a linux box only a few months ago)

My dev box is OSX 10.8, Production server is RHEL for front-end and Ubuntu for the Perl eval Machine. I run on EC2. See the full stack [details here](http://tryperl.com/about).

Any detailed answer will be will appreciated and rewarded with rep and unicorn dust :)

Comment: Take a look at Linux Containers as well.  This allows you to run processes in a very restricted environment.  http://nigel.mcnie.name/blog/a-five-minute-guide-to-linux-containers-for-debian

Comment: +1 Ohh thanks a lot @Dave this is very interesting. Do you think I can run one of those on EC2 though? The ec2 instance is a virtual machine itself. I'll give it a go tho :)

Comment: Perl will read the code from STDIN, so `open(my $fh, '|-', 'perl', '--', @args_for_script)` will do.

Comment: @ikegami Thank for your reply. where should I put `$code` or How do I include `$code` into the line you've mentioned?

Comment: `print($fh $code); close($fh);`

Comment: @ikegami Really sorry to bother you but, seems I'm having a warning (`readline() on unopened filehandle`) when I do : `my @r = <fh>;` , I also tried : `while(<fh>) {}` and iterated over? I need the **result in a string**.

Comment: `$fh` ne `fh`, the former is a variable. Use `<$fh>` instead of `<fh>`.

Comment: Hey thanks @bart unfortunately if `@args_for_script=('Hello');` then I get :`Can't open perl script "Hello": No such file or directory`

Comment: yeah, reading from `perl`'s STDIN ain't gonna work. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ikegami essentially I want to do `perl somefile.pl args_str`, without physically creating somefile.pl. I have the **content** of `somefile.pl` and `$args_str` both in string variables.

Comment: Oops, should be `open(my $fh, '|-', 'perl', '-', @args_for_script)` (a single dash). Tested with `perl -e'open(my $fh, "|-", "perl", "-", "abc") or die; print $fh q{print ">$ARGV[0]<\n"}; close($fh);'`

Comment: @ikegami hey! It worked :D I wrote the `open()..close()` in a seperate `.pl` file which I call from the web method with backticks so I can capture the STDOUT. Anyway, thanks a ton :)

Comment: Ah, you want to capture STDOUT? Use IPC::Run.

Comment: @ikegami yes! The `print $fh $code` prints to STDOUT, so now I put that into a file and then run it within my project with backticks to capture it's output. You're saying IPC is better?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24500/discussion-between-gideon-and-ikegami)

Comment: @gideon Yes, you should be able to use linux containers on EC2.  I believe this is part of how Heroku works.

Comment: Have you checked out `chroot`?

Comment: @aidan `chroot` I think isn't enough when you look at the whole picture. And especially since people have [broken out](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=break+out+of+chroot&aq=0&oq=break+out+of+ch&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3.3379&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1). What I did do is study FreeBSD jails, a little OpenVZ and Linux Containers and I think I have something worked out very nicely :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 13 days of hard work, I finally did it!!

I explored [FreeBSD Jails](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html), my [lack of networking](https://serverfault.com/questions/481936/nslookup-fails-inside-freebsd-jail) experience and the fact that I had to rebuild the OS many times drove me away. FreeBSD is really cool though!! I'll get back to it soon.

I looked bleakly at [OpenVZ](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite) and then thanks to [@ewwhite](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite) I revisited [Linux Containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) and gave it a proper shot.

The docs aren't great but [this article](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2011/10/virtualization-ec2-cloud-using-lxc) really helped with everything.

- I setup multiple containers under a load balancer : [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/).
- I have a perl installation inside each container with the cpan modules I need.
- My *PerlExecutor* application is a Dancer app that runs on [Starman](https://metacpan.org/module/Starman), it runs under owned by a *limited user* which has less privileges and has limits in [limits.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/limits.conf.5.html)
- The container is blocked from the internet.

**One Limitation** :  I don't know much about networking so I blocked the jails from the internet by disabling port forwarding on the host. However, the jails still need to be on the network for the host to communicate to it, as a result, you can still do a **ping** inside the jail which will resolve the domain but it **won't respond**. So any web requests inside fail. I also do a string scan for `Ping` and block it.

Any suggestions or improvements will be very welcome!

I'd like to thank [@JakeFeasel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808921/jake-feasel) [@ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) [@ewwhite](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite) [@chris-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213991/chris-s) and the guys at ubuntu.SE and unix.SE for their help :

This is what it looks like:

[image: TryPerl Architecture Diagram]

Comment: FYI Re: FreeBSD Jails, you don't need to rebuild the OS repeatedly (maybe once, and there are ways around that too) - cf. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-freebsd-jail-with-ezjail/ ; Linux containers (properly configured) are a good solution too though :)

Comment: @voretaq7 true but I lack unix/networking experience so it was a little hard. I did feel awesome playing with FreeBSD and will probably  come back to it soon. Mostly I was just stuck getting the jail to hook up to the internet.